# LinkedIn API Job Search

Tags: api, rest, linkedin-api

I've searched for similar questions - there are many - but all seem to be unanswered. So I will ask it again, if allowed.

Does any API from LinkedIn currently offer an endpoint to do a job search? The functionality on the LI website is a bit limited in my opinion, so I want to be able to get a more comprehensive list that I can analyse by different parameters.

I've checked out the Talent pages, but it seems more geared toward posting, and not searching.

Sing-in with LI also doesn't offer any useful endpoints.

Somewhere someone said something about a service called Voyager, but that doesn't really provide a lot of info, as these pages do.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, there is no API available for job searching on LinkedIn*. I did some work with an applicant tracking system (ATS) tool before that integrates with LI to allow posting of job adverts and I think the only APIs are orientated towards posting adverts and that kind of thing**.

I think that over the years since LI was acquired they have gradually scaled down the third party integrations and locked down their services more.

*https://developer.linkedin.com/product-catalog

**https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/